# adminer only displays one database

Tags: adminer

I download `Adminer 4.2.5`  from https://www.adminer.org/#download which is just one php file around `414 kB` in size. I placed this in /localhost/ and was able to log in to database without any issues. But the only problem is that, I have about 24 databases, and adminer only shows tables and contents from 1 database.

This database also happens to be the first one indexed as it starts with letters `ab..` so I am guessing it is only grabbing it, but this is not the database I want to fetch. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Adminer will only ever show one database at a time.

You can switch databases very simply, by using the standard links at the top of your screen (just to the left of your "logout" button). I.e.:

```
MySQL » Server » yourDatabaseName » Table: yourTableName
```

In this example, clicking on "Server" will return a list of all of the databases to which you have access.

If you can not see a database which you know to exist, you may have a permission and/or access error.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy alternative.

While logging in with a username and password, there's an option of typing the database name. If the database exists and the user has the rights, the tables in the DB will open up.